# Determine ValueRank and ArrayDimensions in opcua-asyncio if not present in server

Tags: python, opc-ua

I'm using https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio and wondering how to receive the ValueRank and ArrayDimensions (at runtime) if the server sets ValueRank to Any (-2) and does not set ArrayDimensions.

As I understood from a Rockwell document (https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/wp/opcua-wp001_-en-e.pdf) the data I receive in read_value() should be self-describing.
I wonder how I can receive that information in opcua-asyncio.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible:

```
var: Variant = await n.read_data_type_as_variant_type()
if var.is_array:
    demensions = var.Dimension # Optional[List[Int32]]
```